# 'Ubuntu software' wrongly seems needing to update

Tags: package-management, update-manager

The icon suitcase of `Ubuntu 20.04` shows now a downward arrow seeming a need to update. But it seems that there is nothing to update and also when I click on `Ubuntu Software` the application shows a transparent windows difficulting what to chose.

I think this is happening after a problem with a broken package that I removed using `sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq <package_name>` . First I updated from 18.04 where the problem initially appeared to 20.04.

The result of `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` is:

```
Hit:1 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal InRelease
Hit:2 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://pt.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
Hit:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
(base) sergio@hug:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 was EOL at 23rd January 2020. Please upgrade to 19.10.

Comment: I have upgraded to 20.04 and the arrow problem remains. And when I click on the `Ubuntu software` icon the application freezes.

Comment: `Ubuntu software` app does not freeze but shows a transparent window that difficult working with it.